# Understanding a part of Dijkstra Shortest path in java code

Tags: java, data-structures, shortest-path, dijkstra

Can any one explain this code to me which is a part of a java code as an application for data structures for Dijkstra shortest path

```
 PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(vertices, new Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> p1, Pair<Integer, Integer> p2) {
            int key1 = p1.getKey();
            int key2 = p2.getKey();
            return key1-key2;
        }
    });
```

Note : The full code is

```
public String Shortest_Path(int sourceVertex){
    boolean[] SPT = new boolean[vertices];
    int [] distance = new int[vertices];

    for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
        distance[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(vertices, new Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> p1, Pair<Integer, Integer> p2) {
            int key1 = p1.getKey();
            int key2 = p2.getKey();
            return key1-key2;
        }
    });

    distance[0] = 0;
    Pair<Integer, Integer> p0 = new Pair<>(distance[0],0);
    pq.add(p0);

    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
        Pair<Integer, Integer> extractedPair = pq.poll();
        int extractedVertex = extractedPair.getValue();
        if(SPT[extractedVertex] == false) {
            SPT[extractedVertex] = true;

            LinkedList<Edge> list = adjacencylist[extractedVertex];
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Edge edge = list.get(i);
                int destination = edge.destination;

                if (SPT[destination] == false) {
                    int newKey =  distance[extractedVertex] + edge.weight ;
                    int currentKey = distance[destination];
                    if(currentKey>newKey){
                        Pair<Integer, Integer> p = new Pair<>(newKey, destination);
                        pq.add(p);
                        distance[destination] = newKey;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I  have posted, Could you check that. hope this works

Answer (score 1):

This is the PriorityQueue used to get the minimum weight edge in your code it's `Pair`

The comparator that declared to the constructor of PQ used to compare two pairs to heapify

the PQ and get the minimum edge, So when you call `Poll()` method will pick up the minimum

edge between vertices

```
PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(vertices, new Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> p1, Pair<Integer, Integer> p2) {
            int key1 = p1.getKey();
            int key2 = p2.getKey();
            return key1-key2;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `pq.poll()` in your code, the priority queue returns the minimum weight edge. This is done by ensuring the elements of the priority queue are ordered in the ascending order of the wights.

Since edges are represented as `Pair` objects, natural ordering is not defined. The code you have asked is where the sorting criteria of the PriorityQueue is specified. ie. A `Pair` has 2 data. a key and a value. In this code, it is specified that, compare the `key`s to sort the PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the two good answers by [sc0der](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61736511/3992939) and by [saki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61737053/3992939):

From [PriorityQueue constuctor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator)):

> Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator

From [Comperator documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects.

and:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.